# Issue Publishing Power BI Paginated Report with Custom Assembly for QR Code Generation

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, ssrs-2012, assemblies

I am currently facing an issue while attempting to publish a Power BI paginated report to the Power BI Service. The report includes a custom assembly that I'm using to generate QR codes based on item numbers from a database. [Here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/generate-qr-code-barcodes-in-an-ssrs-report-with-the-qrcoder-library) is a link to the tutorial on how to use the QRCoder library in SSRS.

For the report to work on my local machine I had to install the assemblies to the global assembly cache (GAC) and embed some code in the report.

When I try to publish the report I get the following error:

```
PaginatedReportAuthoringError: Report is invalid. ErrorCode: rsErrorLoadingCodeModule, Details: Error while loading code module: "QRCoderImageToByteArray, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3016ec4525f0585e". Details: Could not load file or assembly "QRCoderImageToByteArray, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3016ec4525f0585e" or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Is it possible to get this solution to work on the Power BI Service?

Comment: Custom assemblies are not supported in paginated reports on Power BI.

Comment: Thanks, I added it as a [feature request](https://ideas.fabric.microsoft.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=b89efd24-4e46-ee11-a81c-000d3a0e5125) on Microsoft Fabric.